# Socket send buffer queue stuck in Samsung

Tags: android, sockets, samsung-mobile

I'm developing an Qt Android app that sends UDP audio packets every 10 ms. In some devices like Google Pixel 2 it works fine and data arrives to the server on time. However in Samsung devices like S8 and S9 packet sending is delayed every some seconds. Researching on this issue I've done this experiment: just before sending a new packet I query the socket send buffer size

```
...
int qsizeSnd = 0, qsizeRcv = 0;
ioctl( _sd, TIOCOUTQ, &qsizeSnd );
ioctl( _sd, SIOCINQ, &qsizeRcv );
    qDebug() << "[SOCKET] SEND BUFFER SIZE: " << qsizeSnd << " RCV SIZE: " << qsizeRcv << ")";
```

While Pixel 2 always shows a queue size of 0 (this means everything was sent), Samsung devices queues, for some moments up to 18Kb.

[image]

Anyone know what could be happening in samsung and how can I speed up socket send?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:** This only happens with WiFi. Using 4G it reports "Send Buffer Size: 0" (the same than Pixel 2 which works fine)

Comment: Just send one packet. Then wait until it gets send. How long did you have to wait?

Comment: I couldn't tell that because Qt configure sockets as non-blocking. However packets are mostly sent. The situation in the screenshot happens every a couple of seconds, not always. See my Edit 1 please.

Comment: ??? You could see if there is a client who receives it. Then do a test with sending a packet every 10 seconds. Are they received every ten seconds? Then make interval smaller.

Comment: For tcp\ip iit is quite normal that outgoing data is buffered until the sendbuffer is filled or a certain amount of time has passed. Think for udp\ip the same applies. In that sense the Samsung acts normal. For tcp\ip you can add a flush() statement or set the buffer size to 0. Dont know for udp.

Comment: Sending every 10 seconds packets are received every ten seconds.

Comment: I think you are refering to Nagle algorithm: AFAIK it only applies to TCP/IP, in fact the option is called TCP_NODELAY, to turn it off. I'm sure this is related to wifi interface but I don't know why it only affects Samsung (and how can I fix it)

Comment: Last update: it seems a background task performed in samsung devices like a wifi scan that cannot be turned off and locks the wireless interface, blocking it to send and receive.